# Scrapy startproject giving weird error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm almost positive this is because of python2.7 vs python3.5 issues but I haven't found a way to fix it.

I run

```
    $ scrapy startproject test1
```

and get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/scrapy", line 9, in <module>
          load_entry_point('Scrapy==1.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 122, in execute
          cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 46, in _get_commands_dict
          cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 29, in _get_commands_from_module
          for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-     packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 21, in _iter_command_classes
    for obj in vars(module).itervalues():
    AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'itervalues'
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is:

```
sudo pip install scrapy==1.1.0rc1
```

Scrapy is now available for Python3.

Answer (score 2):

As of writing (4th of August 2015), scrapy is simply not supported in python 3. It is often mentioned, but there has never been a full translation.

It has to do with the fact that Twisted (an integral part of Scrapy) is not supported in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Python 3.5's dict type no longer has the method 'itervalues'. Unless they fix the issue, you might be forced to use a prior version of Python.

EDIT:

If you want, you could change the code, and replace the function itervalues() with items(). I don't think that would be a good idea, but it can be a workaround if you must use 3.5

Comment: How do I force scrapy to use python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

python3 , use dict.items() instead of dict.iteritems()

iteritems() was removed in python3, so you can't use this method anymore.

A simple fix would be to do a fresh installation of scrapy in python2.7 (Link your python default to 2.7)
Then do a fresh insstalaltion of python-pip which will use python2.7 instead of python3+ as:
sudo apt-get install python-pip
After pip installion use:
sudo pip install Scrapy

To test scrapy do:
scrapy fetch  http://www.example.com/some/page.html

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to use Python 2.7 with Scrapy.  Scrapy is heavily reliant on Twisted (although, only a small portion of it), which is not compatible with Python 3.

Since you're planning on running multiple versions of Python on the same system, I'd recommend you look into `virtualenv` (I'd actually recommend this regardless of what you're doing on the system, it's just THAT helpful).  Virtualenv is a tools which allows you to setup and install a "virtual" python installation in its own directory with it's own packages.

A couple good guides can be found [here](http://www.simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial-part-2/), and [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).